# Ошибка StackOverflowException при возврате фокуса

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне надо чтоб при потере фокуса проверялось условие, если true то элемент должен получить фокус, как исправить ошибку?

```
NameColumn.LostFocus += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (NameColumn.GetValue(HintAssist.HelperTextProperty) != "")
    {
         NameColumn.Focus(); //StackOverflowException
    }
};
```

Comment: Этот форум был создан для этого вопроса

Comment: @Lofectr совпадение, не думаю

Comment: А какого типа `NameColumn`?

Comment: @VladD TextBox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
NameColumn.LostFocus += async (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (NameColumn.GetValue(HintAssist.HelperTextProperty) != "")
    {
         await Task.Yield();
         NameColumn.Focus();
    }
};
```

Более изящный вариант такой:

```
NameColumn.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += (o, e) =>
{
    if (NameColumn.GetValue(HintAssist.HelperTextProperty) != "")
        e.Handled = true;
};
```

---

Проблема в вашем коде состоит вот в чём. После отправки события `LostFocus` код WPF синхронно устанавливает фокус на целевой элемент. Посмотреть можно [тут](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationCore/System/Windows/Input/FocusManager.cs,238): изменение фокуса вызывает изменение `IsFocused`, которое отправляет `LostFocus` (в рамках которого вы возвращаете фокус назад), а после установки фокуса таки на целевой элемент ваш `TextBox` снова теряет фокус, что приводит к рекурсивному запуску той же цепочки и переполнению стека.

Решение — либо возвращать фокус позже, когда смена фокуса полностью состоялась, или (более изящно) отменить смену фокуса на Preview-событии.